# Error while opening a second window from first window the second time in Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp

I have two windows: `Window1` is more like Splash Screen with an `ComboBox` to choose the excel file. `Window2` has various textboxes, datagrids, tabs which will load the data corresponding to that file.

Now I have a `Button` called `"Go`" in `Window1` which has the following code:

```
switch (ComboBoxAreaList.Text)
            {
                case "Area1":
                    Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocation = "C:\\ProgramName\\Area1.xlsx";
                    break;
                case "Area2":
                    Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocation = "C:\\ProgramName\\Area2.xlsx";
                    break;
                case "Area3":
                    Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocation = "C:\\ProgramName\\Area3.xlsx";
                    break;
                default: MessageBox.Show("Error!");
                    break;
            }

            MainWindow AreaDataWindow = new MainWindow();
            AreaDataWindow.Show();
            Close();
```

I have a `Button` called `"ChangeAreaData"` in `Window2` which has the following code:

```
SplashScreen NewSplashScreen = new SplashScreen();
            NewSplashScreen.Show();
            Close();
```

Initially, `Window1` will show up and user clicks the `Go` button, the `Window2` will load without any issues. Then I go back to `Window1` using `ChangeArea` button and change the data by choosing an item in `ComboBox`. Then load `Window2` again by clicking `Go` button, I will get the following error in Windows **XP**:

```
AppName: area logs status.exe    AppVer: 1.0.0.0     ModName: kernel32.dll
ModVer: 5.1.2600.7475    Offset: 00034f03
```

So just the second time, it's throwing that error. It's working fine in Windows 10 and 8. But not in Windows XP. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Surely that button code closes window 1...

Comment: Have you debugged your code

Comment: I'm testing that program in VirtualBox, on a plain Windows XP installation. Just wanted to make it compatible with XP too. How can I debug that in XP? Weird thing is how can it work so well for the first time, but throws an error for the second time.

Comment: The code is the problem, and likely not XP, is my guess, though its hard to tell, if you put try catch around things can you catch any error?

Comment: Got this error: `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '52'. ---> System.IO.FileFormatException: The image format is unrecognized. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F07`

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971751/the-image-format-is-unrecognized-depending-on-monitor

Comment: I didn't thought icon was the problem. It's working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mm8 for pointing me out the solution. I just need to choose .png instead of .ico for Icon Property in XAML, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971751/the-image-format-is-unrecognized-depending-on-monitor)